# Android Studio Lint for finding invalid component classes?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, lint, androidx

Long story short, Android Studio's new Refactor feature to `Migrate to Android X` is buggy. In the end, I ended up with dozens of invalid, incomplete, non-existent component classes in my XML files and the compiler didn't complain. Only when testing at runtime did I realize what it's done.

Is there a lint option to find invalid class names / component types so that it flags something like this (which does not exist):

```
<androidx.widget.AppCompatSeekBar>....</androidx.widget.AppCompatSeekBar>
```

The actual class name is `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar`. I've had to do a lot of manual find and replace, but I feel reluctant posting this as an update and break an app that was working perfectly before.